# Why is DocumentBuilder.parse() not working

Tags: java, xml

I have read several posts about how to use the `DocumentBuilder.parse()` function for getting a document object.

```
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

was returning `[#document: null]` which as I found does not necessarily mean it is empty. However, after inspecting it more, I have found that it is in fact empty.

I am building the String xml and have used an xml validator, (and pasted into eclipse and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to format it. This is usually my first try to see if something is well formed) to show it is valid xml. I decided to break out each part of the `parse()` parameters so I could step through and watch to make sure they were working correctly.

My code is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;        
try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
    InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
    Document document = builder.parse(is);          

    return document;
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

sr and is appear to work correctly until I execute the builder.parse(is) line. As soon as this executes, the sr.str value becomes null and same with is.characterInputStream.str. This seems odd to me, is this expected? This has been driving me crazy, any input would be great!

edit- my xml string is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Feed Title</title>
        <link>Feed Link</link>
        <description>Feed Description</description>
        <item>
            <title>Item Title</title>
            <link>Item Link</link>
            <description>Item Description</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Another Item</title>
            <link>Another Link</link>
            <description>Another Description</description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Can you tell us or give us an example of what `xml` is?

Comment: I believe this should be closed. my apologies to the SO community

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> As soon as this executes, the sr.str value becomes null and same with is.characterInputStream.str. This seems odd to me, is this expected?

Yes, I'd say so. `DocumentBuilder.parse` is closing the reader. `StringReader.close()` sets `str` to `null`. This is an implementation detail of `StringReader` - but you should *expect* to see implementation details when you poke around private fields when debugging. (It's also not documented that `DocumentBuilder.parse` will close the input it's given, but it seems reasonable.)

It's unclear what the problem *is* with your XML, but this part of the behaviour is entirely reasonable.

I would strongly recommend that you try your code with the simplest XML you can think of, e.g. `"<foo />"`.

The code you've shown so far is fine. Here's a short but complete program to show it working:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
       DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder builder;
       builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
       StringReader sr = new StringReader("<foo />");
       InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
       Document document = builder.parse(is);
       System.out.println(document.getDocumentElement().getTagName());
   }
}
```

Comment: Although this is reasonable, do you have a reference?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: No, it's an implementation detail - as is the presence of the private field `str`. Basically when you're debugging, you uncover implementation details... Will edit to indicate this.

Comment: thank you for your response. Frankly I am baffled by this. your test case worked great and I saw foo output. I the values for sr and is got wiped out again. I then plugged that in over my original code (only difference really was the println) and the output was rss. That sounds good. what is getting me is that document's firstChild is the rss node, but that node has a null firstChild. Is the xml I posted invalid?

Comment: @Aheinlein: No, that XML is fine. The first child node of the rss node is the `channel` element (using my code, and `document.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild().getNodeName()`). Basically I think the error is in how you're using your `Document`, and you haven't shown us that at all :(

Comment: I guess this turns out to be another duplicate of the same things I read a lot about why the document's output is null when it is working correctly... I apologize for wasting your time. I am using Mule ESB, inside a groovy script I am calling this java and returning the xml document to the flow. My real problem is the flow not reading the xml document. I am very new to mule and have not done much with xml in Java. Looks to me like a http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .I marked your answer correct, but This should be closed. Thank you

Comment: Why does a C# one liner have to be so complex in Java?